# How to add repository information in table format in dspace home page?

Tags: dspace

I want to add repository information in the base of table-format in Dspace6.0 Home page. Should I edit this XML file- DSpace-installation `directory/config/news-xmlui.xml`?

I have done some changes about that, but I couldn't get proper results.

Comment: Hi! Depending on what you're trying to achieve, and assuming you're using the XMLUI version, editing the news-xmlui page might do the trick indeed. That page uses the DRI syntax, see https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/DRI+Schema+Reference#DRISchemaReference-table as a starting point, and then chain to the different sub-elements of . the "table" tag. If you're trying to get a specific result, it may be useful to post a capture or link to your current result and a mockup of the expected final rendering.

Comment: Thank u so much, sir. Problem is solved.